# Handling large inputs in Programming Language Models

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am using CodeBERT and CodeT5 models to generate embeddings for my Python code dataset. Specifically, I am using the `codebert-base` and `codet5-small` models from HuggingFace. However, these models have a maximum input sequence length of 512 tokens. When tokenizing the Python codes, I find that their length is approximately 10 times larger than the maximum input sequence length. My intention is not to perform any downstream tasks; rather, I want to obtain the embeddings for the purpose of clustering. I am wondering how to handle these lengthy input codes aside from removing less important parts from the inputs.